# RequireJS with Knockout - Applying bindings multiple times

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm trying to streamline our development of KnockoutJS components using RequireJS. The problem is that it's saying I'm applying bindings multiple times to the same element.

**require-config.js**

```
var require = {
  baseUrl: ".",
  paths: {
    "bootstrap": "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min",
    "jquery": "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
    "knockout": "bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout",
    "text": "bower_components/text/text"
  },
  shim:{
    "bootstrap": {deps: ["jquery"]}
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
define(["jquery", "knockout", "bootstrap"], function($, ko){
    ko.components.register("sel-text", { require: "components/selecttextarea/selecttextarea" });
    ko.applyBindings({});
});
```

**selecttextarea.js - (the component I've created)**

```
define(["knockout", "text!./selecttextarea.html"], function(ko, template){
  function SelTextareaViewModel(params){
     var self = this;
     self.items = ko.observableArray(params.items);
     self.caption = ko.observable();
  }

  return{ viewModel: SelTextareaViewModel, template: template};
});
```

### Trying to use the component

**index.html**

```
  <div class="row" id="asd">
       <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.selectItems)"></pre>
       <sel-text params="items: $root.selectItems"></sel-text>
  </div>

      ...

<script>
require(['js/page1']);
</script>
```

**page1.js**

```
require(["jquery", "knockout"], function($, ko){

  var data = [{"val": 0, "text": "Hello"}, {"val": 1, "text": "Bloody"}, {"val": 2, "text": "World"}];
    function SimpleViewModel(d){
      var self = this;
      self.selectItems = ko.observableArray(d);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new SimpleViewModel(data), $('#asd')[0]);
});
```

If I remove the `<pre>` tag it doesn't show the error, it's like it's trying to applyBindings to each element within `$('#asd')[0]`.

I'm baffled, any suggestions?

### Update

From the comments it was made clear to not applyBindings in my main.js. This would work in single page application if you look at [Steve Sanderson's Knockout Triage repo](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-triage/tree/master/src)

How I got it working was to remove the `applyBindings` from `main.js` but then require them in `page1.js`: `require(["jquery", "knockout", "js/main"], function($, ko)`.

Ideally the components would be registered globally and I wouldn't even have to consider them on a page level but hey-ho. I do have a working example I did at work yesterday (but I forgot to grab a copy of my code) and had it working fine.

Comment: On a side note: why are you doing `ko.applyBindings({})` in your main.js file, but *also* calling `applyBindings` in page1.js? That makes no sense. The first one kind of makes sense, if you were to call it with a more detailed root viewmodel, that has an (observable) member for the SimpleViewModel you can then create later on.

Comment: Also, at the end of your post you mention "it doesn't show the error", but what error is that? You don't mention getting any error.

Comment: @JotaBe Steve Sanderson has a repo called [Knockout-triage](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-triage/tree/master) in his startup.js he is applying his bindings with routing in there. The issue I'm facing is applying bindings on a page level too.

Comment: @Jezzabeanz I'm sorry. Yes, you're right. I didn't know the last pattern, which is also well documented at the end of ko component registration doc. Now that I see it, your code looks fine. The only part that I don't understand is why applyBindings is called in your main.js, as well as in your page1.js

Comment: as @JotaBe pointed out, applyBindings shows up twice in your code so probably one applies bindings after which the second applies some bindings on the same elements the first one did.

Comment: I've managed to get it working, whether or not it is good practice is beyond me. 
I remove the apply bindings from main.js and required it in page1.js ["js/main"] which will still register the components. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are standardizing on a set of knockout components, I suggest registering the component inside the module.  In the sample below, the code uses the [special 'exports' dependency](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#magic) to define the module's return value. This alleviates the need to have a *return* statement at the end of the module.

```
define([
  'knockout', 
  'exports', 
  'text!/.select-text.html'
], function (ko, selectArea, template) {

   function SelectArea(params) { ... }

   selectArea.viewModel = SelectArea; 
   selectArea.template = template;

   ko.components.register('select-area', selectArea);

});
```

The advantage of registering the component inside the module is that everything is self-contained and can be documented.  Then if you have a lot of components, you can create a simple *all.js* module to include all the component definitions. e.g.

```
define([
  'components/selectArea',
  'components/selectMultiple',
  ....
 ], function () { });
```

Then just include the *all.js* in the *require()* call, or the *define()* block that calls *ko.applyBindings()*, and all the components should get registered before you call ko.applyBindings().

```
require([
  'knockout',
  ...
  'components/all'
], function (ko, ...) {
   ko.applyBindings(...);
}
```

If you have some page specific components, then you might need to vary this pattern.  And one important thing to note, try not to have the knockout component AMD module have any side effects.  It should just define the view model and template.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it was made clear to not applyBindings in my main.js. This would work in single page application if you look at Steve Sanderson's Knockout Triage repo

How I got it working was to remove the `applyBindings` from `main.js` but then require them in `page1.j`s: `require(["jquery", "knockout", "js/main"], function($, ko)`.

Ideally the components would be registered globally and I wouldn't even have to consider them on a page level but hey-ho. I do have a working example I did at work yesterday (but I forgot to grab a copy of my code) and had it working fine.

Comment: You can also use custom loaders to avoid the need to register your components. If you read this docs, you'll understand what it means: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-loaders.html